Is it better for a flap and/or aileron to be an airfoil shape or simply replicating the trailing edge shape of the wing?
I am designing a UAV with the goals, broadly speaking, of a short take-off and high top-speed. I've already selected the airfoil for the wing itself. The wing is going to have a single slotted flap, no leading edge devices.
I was wondering if having the flap in the shape of an airfoil would provide better aerodynamic properties that would ultimately help achieve a shorter take-off. The alternative would be a flap that takes on the shape of the trailing edge and we be symmetric. I know it is common practice to go with the latter, but how do these compare?
Also, which shape would be better for the aileron?

If you already know your wing airfoil, don't you think you will get better answers when you let us know what it is?

For most control surfaces (including ailerons, elevators, rudder, etc), we use what is called a 'plain flap'.
A plain flap has a simple hinge (rotation only, no translation), with the axis of rotation within the airfoil -- typically centered vertically.  The aft portion of the plain flap maintains the shape of the airfoil, the leading side is usually rounded.
Importantly, the plain flap usually incorporates some sort of seal to prevent flow from going through the gap from the lower to upper side (or vis versa).
Most control surface applications prefer a plain flap because they can be deflected symmetrically -- with essentially equivalent effectiveness in both directions.
Things get more complex when you go to some sort of slotted flap -- a flap where flow intentionally goes through the gap.  In this case, it is important to aerodynamically design the cove and the entirety of the flap.  In this case, the flap(s) will be their own airfoil shape -- but you still want them to package together into a shape like the cruise airfoil.
Doing a proper high lift airfoil design is most likely beyond your capabilities and resources.  However, you should be able to look at existing systems applied to similar cruise airfoils and draw up something that is very representative.
NASA has a lot of reports available online that include high lift airfoils designed to various cruise airfoils.  I would start there.
